# Tortoisegit Show Log - What does a revision without bullet mean?

Tags: tortoisegit

When I view the 'Show Log' in Tortoisegit, some of the revisions are shown without a node/bullet in Graph. What does that mean?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the log dialog all revisions (except working tree changes - as these are uncommitted) have a bullet indicating on which „branch“ they are located.

It can happen, however, that the column is not wide enough.

Comment: Oh my god. That was the issue exactly :D